# How to Update the Date without changing its Time Using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have One Column in the Mytable called StockDate and its DataType is DateTime.

So My Table contains record as follows

```
    SID                StockDate
   -----              ------------
     1                 2011-10-02 09:44:41.170
     2                 2011-10-02 09:48:23.234
```

Here I want to update Only the Date of the StockDate as "2011-09-30". But the time should be same as it is. How to do this? Please I need all your suggestions.

Comment: Kills me when I google a question for myself, land on SO, and the question has no upvotes. Come on people! If you're answering the question, it's worthy of an upvote.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Work out the different in whole days and subtract that...

```
UPDATE
   MyTable
SET
   StockDate = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, StockDate, '20110930'), StockDate)
WHERE
   ...
```

Note the use of the yyyymmdd for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=SQL.90).aspx

You could probably use DATEDIFF and DATEADD to get yourself to 9/30/2011 without changing the time.

Comment: Your link is MySQL, question says SQL Server. The two RDBMS have different syntax and different workings...

Comment: Your right, I think I misread MyTable as MySql, though both RDBMS have DATEDIFF and DATEADD functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dateadd`, `datediff` [functions](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/10/sql-server-retrieve-select-only-date-part-from-datetime-best-practice/).